# Leaflet in Vue3 use SFC component as popup. Is there any risk of memory leak while recreating same Vue3 App?

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuejs3

### Question

Hi,
I have a Leaflet 1.8.0 map. I'm populating the markers with a GeoJSON object and I'm using a Vue component as the marker popup. I'm not sure I need to recreate each time the component because I suspect a memory leak.

Is there a better way than recreating the App on each popupover ?
Is App.unmount() sufficient while firing popupclose ?

### My working code:

1. I create a "filteredPlaces" GeoJSON object containing the markers I want.
2. I compute the bounding box
3. I loop all the markers for binding a L.Layer.Popup and listening "popupopen" and "popupclose" event
4. On popupopen I create and mount my custom SFC component
5. On popupclose I unmount my component

### Mounted() logic

```js
    mounted() {
        const filteredPlaces = { type: "FeatureCollection" as typeof places.type, features: places.features.filter((place: GeoJSON.FlyingPlace) => { return place.properties.default }) }
        const box = this.getBBox(filteredPlaces);
        const map: L.Map = L.map('map', { attributionControl: true }).fitBounds([[box.latMin, box.longMin], [box.latMax, box.longMax]]);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            accessToken: mapboxConf.token
        }).addTo(map);
        L.geoJSON(places as unknown as GeoJsonObject, {
            onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
                const _feature = feature as unknown as GeoJSON.FlyingPlace;
                if (_feature.properties && _feature.properties.name) {
                    let baliseFFVL:App<Element> = null;
                    layer.bindPopup(`<div id="link-${_feature.properties.slug}"></div>`)
                        .on("popupopen", () => {
                                console.log(`create BaliseFFVL component for ${_feature.properties.name}`)
                                baliseFFVL = createApp(BaliseFFVL, { id: _feature.properties.idBalise, slug: _feature.properties.slug }) as App<Element>;
                                baliseFFVL.mount(`#link-${_feature.properties.slug}`);
                        })
                        .on("popupclose", () => {
                            console.log(`close BaliseFFVL component ${_feature.properties.name}`);
                            baliseFFVL.unmount();
                        })
                }
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    },
```

### Bonus my getBBox methods

because I don't find some in Leaflet

```js
        /**
         * GeoJSON.FlyingPlace extends GeoJSON.Feature
         * @param data A Collection of GeoJSON.FlyingPlace features
         */
        getBBox(data: GeoJSON.FlyingPlaceCollection) {
            let bounds = { longMin: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, latMin: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, longMax: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, latMax: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }
            let coordinates: GeoJSON.Position;
            for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                coordinates = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
                bounds.longMin = bounds.longMin < coordinates[0] ? bounds.longMin : coordinates[0]; //Longitude
                bounds.latMin = bounds.latMin < coordinates[1] ? bounds.latMin : coordinates[1]; //latitude
                bounds.longMax = bounds.longMax > coordinates[0] ? bounds.longMax : coordinates[0];
                bounds.latMax = bounds.latMax > coordinates[1] ? bounds.latMax : coordinates[1];
            }
            return bounds;
        }
```